# Filling a password form with Splinter

Tags: python, forms, passwords, webdriver, splinter

I'm trying to fill two forms and login to my banks website.

I can get the first form for the username to fill but I can't seem to get the form for the password to fill.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
from splinter import Browser

username2 = '***'
password2 = '***'

browser2 = Browser()
browser2.visit('http://mijn.ing.nl')

browser2.find_by_css('.firstfield').fill(username2)
browser2.find_by_id('#easnhbcc').fill(password2)
```

and this is the full traceback:

```
/usr/local/bin/python2 "/Users/narekaramjan/Dropbox/Python/Python 273/Test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/narekaramjan/Dropbox/Python/Python 273/Test.py", line 26, in <module>
    browser2.find_by_id('#easnhbcc').fill(password2)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/splinter/element_list.py", line 73, in __getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'ElementList' object has no attribute 'fill'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have also tried:

```
browser2.find_by_name('easnhbcc').fill(password2)
```

How can I get the password form to fil?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
from splinter import Browser     

# Define the username and password
username2 = '***'
password2 = '***'

# Choose the browser (default is Firefox)
browser2 = Browser()

# Fill in the url
browser2.visit('https://mijn.ing.nl/internetbankieren/SesamLoginServlet')

# Find the username form and fill it with the defined username
browser2.find_by_id('gebruikersnaam').first.find_by_tag('input').fill(username2)

# Find the password form and fill it with the defined password
browser2.find_by_id('wachtwoord').first.find_by_tag('input').fill(password2)

# Find the submit button and click
browser2.find_by_css('.submit').first.click()

# Print the current url
print browser2.url

# Print the current browser title
print browser2.title

# Print the current html source code
print browser2.html
```

Comment: Don't perticularly like the * imports... It makes it unclear where names come from. Did `Browser` come from `selenium`  or from `splinter`? And if it came from `splinter`, why bother with the `selenium` import? "Explicit is better than implicit." -- The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that you are trying to fill a list of elements. You need to select just one of the elements in the list. You probably want something like:

```
find_by_name('foo').first.fill()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without getting too deep into your code, and taking a quick look at that site (where the ID's have changed, I might add), I would say you probably added an extra '#' into your find_by_id('#easnhbcc') call. The '#' is typical CSS language for an ID, but the find_by_id() splinter call does not expect it.
either

```
find_by_id('easnhbcc')
```

or

```
find_by_css('#easnhbcc')
```

probably would have done the trick for you.