# How to submit a POST payload with splinter browser in python

Tags: python, post, splinter

I am working with pythons splinter browser library, opening a page and passing data for that page to process in the GET string. I have a need to submit a POST payload because the length of the variables in my GET string is at times exceeding the max GET string length.

I have searched around extensively but can not find a syntax example or anything saying there is a way to send POST data without clicking submit on a form.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer, but i have good experience with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i am in need of a headless browser with cookie and JS support. I have tried requests but it can not interact with the site i am sending the request to.

Comment: If you have a form on that page maybe you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284522/filling-a-password-form-with-splinter)