# Using browser.fill() and getting TypeError: fill() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to fill in an input field on a webpage using this code:

```
from splinter import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver

executable_path = {'executable_path':ChromeDriverManager().install()}
browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path, headless = False)
browser.visit('http://webapps2.rrc.state.tx.us/EWA/wellboreQueryAction.do')
**browser.find_by_name('searchArgs.leaseNumberArg').fill('searchArgs.leaseNumberArg',
                                                    '160895')**
```

I get this error:
TypeError: fill() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I've used the same syntax to successfully fill other input fields.  As far as I can tell the only difference here is that the input field name contains a '.' which I think possibly relates to a column of some kind of data structure.

Any thought on how to get past this road block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used `splinter` before so I'm not sure myself. But after reading your code how about writing your code like this ?

```py
browser.find_by_name('searchArgs.leaseNumberArg').fill('160895')
```

If I'm not wrong, you already have the element by using `find_by_name()` so you don't need to pass it second time inside the fill methods. Seems logic.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17298427/5527968) is another post that show how to use `fill()`.

Comment: Brilliant, that did it.  Thanks for your input!